# Implementing optimization part of blind deconvolution in Python

Tags: python, convex-optimization

I am trying to implement the paper [Qi Shan, Zhaorong Li, Jiaya Jia, Chi-Keung Tang - Fast Image/Video Upsampling](http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/%7Eleojia/projects/upsampling/upsampling_sa08.pdf) and need some help with implementing minimizing an energy function (7) shown below.

Here is a summary:

Image degradation process from H (high resolution) to L (low resolution) is:

$$ \tilde{H} = f \otimes H, \ L = \tilde{H} \downarrow^{d}$$

where $\downarrow^{d}$ is a decimating (subsampling) operator with factor d and where $\tilde{H}$ is the linearly filtered high-resolution image. If these two steps can be approximately inverted, that is, by first upsampling the image and then deconvolving it using the linear filter, a reliable upsampling process can be yielded.
Instead of minimizing this equation:
$$ \parallel f \otimes H - \tilde{H} \parallel_2^{2}$$

this paper adds a regularization term based on the natural phenomenon that natural image gradients generally follow a heavy-tailed distribution, indicating that most pixels have small gradient magnitudes. Adding a prior term to equation above  makes the deconvolution well-posed and helps find a unique solution.
[image: Phi]

$$
\Phi(x) = \left\{
    \begin{array}\\
        -k|x| & \mbox{if } \ x \le l_t \\
        -(ax^{2}+b) & \mbox{if } \ x \gt l_t \\
    \end{array}
\right.
$$

By incorporating such prior into the regularization term for the deconvolution process, we are subject to minimize the following energy function:

$$ E(H) \propto \ \parallel f \otimes H - \tilde{H} \parallel_2^{2} + \ \lambda_1(\parallel \Phi(\partial_x H) \parallel_1 + \parallel \Phi(\partial_y H) \parallel_1)$$

where $\partial_x H$ and $\partial_y H$ respectively denote the values of the x- and y-direction gradient, and $\lambda_1$ is a weight.

##### Variable substitution:

To make the optimization efficient and robust, this paper uses the variables substitution scheme. By using $\mu = (\mu_x, \mu_y)$ to substitute $\partial H = (\partial_x H, \partial_y H)$, and add an additional term to measure the difference between $\partial H$ and $\mu$:
$$ E(H, \mu) = \ \parallel f \otimes H - \tilde{H} \parallel_2^{2} + \ \lambda_1(\parallel \Phi(\mu_x) \parallel_1 + \parallel \Phi(\mu_y) \parallel_1) + \ \lambda_2(\parallel \mu_x - \partial_x H \parallel_2^{2} + \parallel \mu_y - \partial_y H \parallel_2^{2}) \tag{6}$$

where $\lambda_2$ is a weight to control the relative importance that $\mu$ and $\partial H$ have similar values.

The purpose of using this variable substitution scheme is to separate $\Phi(\partial H)$ from $ \parallel f \otimes H - \tilde{H} \parallel_2^{2}$ in optimization, thus making it possible to use FFT to accelerate the convolution process.

The values of $\mu$ and $\partial H$ will eventually be quite similar, since the weight $\lambda_2$ will be progressively increased in iterations.

- $\mu$ Step: fix $H$ to optimize $\mu$
  $$ E(\mu) = \lambda_1(\parallel \Phi(\mu_x) \parallel_1 + \parallel \Phi(\mu_y) \parallel_1) + \ \lambda_2(\parallel \mu_x - \partial_x H \parallel_2^{2} + \parallel \mu_y - \partial_y H \parallel_2^{2}) \tag{7}$$
  Or,
  $$ E(\mu) = \sum_{x,y} (E(\mu_x (x,y)) + E(\mu_y (x,y))) \tag{8}$$
  Since each $E(\mu(x, y))$ is not related to other energy elements, and it only contains one variable $\mu(x, y)$, we decompose the multi-variable optimization
  problem into a set of single-variable minimization problems. $E(\mu(x, y))$ consists of convex, differentiable pieces, eachof which is minimized separately and the minimum among them is chosen. This optimization step can be completed quickly, resulting in a global minimum for $E(\mu(x, y))$.

How do I approach this problem? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What I dont understand is: what exactly is your problem? You told us what you want to do, gave us some background information regarding the solution. However, it is unclear to me where you are failing or where you get stucked?

Comment: I am not sure where to start from. I think, first, I have to fit image gradient (let's say 1 channel) in x-direction to the piecewise function to get a, b, k values. Then using those values in $\Phi$, I have to minimize $E(\mu)$. I don't know if I am thinking about it right. Also, how do I minimize (7) to get $\mu$?

Comment: @SadHak, Do you have some experience with ADMM?